# Application (job) list empty on Hadoop 2.x

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

I have a Hadoop 2.8.1 installation on a macOS Sierra (Darwin Kernel version 16.7.0) and it's working fine, except the application/tasks tracking.

1) At first, I thought it was a problem with the Resource Manager web interface. So:

- I've copied the yarn-site.xml template to the etc/yarn-site.xml file, but it didn't help.
- I've tried to change the default 'dr. who' user to my Hadoop user on Resource manager (http://localhost:18088/cluster/apps/RUNNING?user.name=myUser), but it didn't help also.

2) Nor even on command line I can track my applications (jobs): yarn application -list returns always empty.

3) Another information: on application INFO outputs, it shows these following lines, but I can't access it.
INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local2009332672_0001

Is it a yarn problem? Should I change another setting file? Thanks!

Comment: What mapreduce framework did you set? **job _local** files aren't using YARN. Look at `mapreduce.framework.name` in `mapred-site`

Comment: Thanks, @cricket_007! I don't have this mapred-site file. I've found this property on mapred-default.xml. It was with value 'local', I changed to 'yarn' and restarted Hadoop. But my application list still is empty. Any other idea?

Comment: You need to rename the default file to mapred-site

Comment: Great, it's working!! Thank you @cricket_007 =)

Comment: Cool. I'll move that comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `mapreduce.framework.name` in `mapred-site.xml`. In your `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`

Set its value to `yarn`.

If you don't have a mapred-site, then copy and rename the mapred-default XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, I was looking for this feature without success. I did changes on the etc/hosts for nothing
The answer is to set mapreduce.framework.name in mapred-site.xmlto yarn as stated by cricket_007. 
This is setting yarn as the default framework for MapReduce operations